# Getting ModuleNotFoundError (No module named 'pkg_resources.extern') while importing spacy

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, spacy

I'm getting module not found error while importing spacy in my jupyter notebook.

**ModuleNotFoundError: (No module named 'pkg_resources.extern')**

Full error log here:

```
ModuleNotFoundError Traceback (most recent call last)
in ()
→ 278 import spacy
279 import logging
280

/python/spacy/2.1.4-py37/exec/lib/spacy/init.py in ()
10 from thinc.neural.util import prefer_gpu, require_gpu
11
—> 12 from .cli.info import info as cli_info
13 from .glossary import explain
14 from .about import version

/python/PROJ/spacy/2.1.4-py37/exec/lib/spacy/cli/init.py in ()
----> 1 from .download import download 

/python/PROJ/spacy/2.1.4-py37/exec/lib/spacy/cli/download.py in ()
9 from wasabi import Printer
10
—> 11 from .link import link
12 from …util import get_package_path
13 from … import about

/python/PROJ/spacy/2.1.4-py37/exec/lib/spacy/cli/link.py in ()
7
8 from …compat import symlink_to, path2str
----> 9 from … import util
10
11

/python/PROJ/spacy/2.1.4-py37/exec/lib/spacy/util.py in ()
3
4 import os
----> 5 import pkg_resources
6 import importlib
7 import re

/user/rahul/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/init.py in ()
55 FileExistsError = OSError
56
—> 57 from pkg_resources.extern import six
58 from pkg_resources.extern.six.moves import urllib, map, filter
59

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named ‘pkg_resources.extern’
```

I followed multiple posts on the similar error and tried reinstalling/upgrading setuptools/pkg_resources, but none of them resolved my issue. This is happening only at my local!  Also, note that this is happening only with spacy, but the error is pointing to python package `pkg_resources`. I'm stuck with this issue for quite long now, any suggestions would be highly apricated.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the issue by deleting the `.local`, `.jupyter` & `.ipython` directories from my user home directory.  The issue went away right after deleting the corrupted local files/directories.

Comment: Saved my day! I had a virtualenv running but the python app (jupyter) was still referring to ${HOME}/.ipython amd ${HOME}/.jupyter. All started after deleting those two directories.

Answer (score 1):

I think in python 3 `pkg_resources/__init__.py` should not contain line `from pkg_resources.extern import six` - this is python 2 related. Somehow you have an older version of `setuptools` targeted at python 2. I suggest you trying to install specific `setuptools` version, e.g `pip install setuptools==56.0.0`.

Comment: As a side note: make sure you're installing it in the correct place / virtual env / python setup - the same you're trying to import `spacy` in.

Comment: Thank you for the answer!  I already tried to install `setuptools` using `pip install setuptools `, but it didnt work. Let me try these:  `pip3 install "setuptools==56.0.0" ` ,   `python3 -m pip3 install "setuptools==56.0.0" ` and `python3 -m pip install "setuptools==56.0.0" `